# убрать переход по прямой ссылке

Tags: php

Есть у меня сайт с единой точкой входа, но при попытке перейти по прямой ссылке можно зайти в закрытые разделы сайта. Как можно запретить переходить на страницы по прямым ссылкам? (Типа example.com/admin/ahome.php не должно работать, а example.com/ahome - должно работать)

Comment: На каждый роут сделать проверку по ролям

Comment: В единой точке входа определяете константу типа `const ALL_RIGHT = 1;`. В каждом файле проверяете - задефайнена ли константа. Если файл открыт в обход точки входа - то константы там нет и можно смело кидать какой-нибудь 40х статус.

Answer (score 1):

Для апача запретить доступ к файлу можно так

```
<FilesMatch ~ "ahome\.php$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

несколько файлов

```
<FilesMatch ~ "(ahome|xxx|example)\.php$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Также можно запретить доступ к папке разместив в ней файл .htacсess со строкой

```
Deny from all
```

Под nginx есть похожая функциональность.

Comment: Всё правильно Вы написали, но кажется вопрос noNameR был в том, чтобы не вообще ограничить доступ к папке или файлу, а возможность переходить по прямым ссылкам на них. Доступ же должен, как я понял, для некоторых случаев оставаться.

Comment: сначала я так же подумал, потом решил что нет. Пусть автор вопроса прояснит это. Можно, например, пароль на директорию поставить.

Answer (score 0):

Не претендую на лучшее решение, но я бы сделал так:

1. Установил бы сессию.
2. При входе на index.php или нужный входящий файл и после манипуляций определяющих роль пользователя (Админ, не админ, может переходить или нет) установить в сессию клиента триггер проверки. Пример : `$_SESSION['trigger'] = "1";`
3. Проверять этот триггер при переходе на страницы с закрытым содержимым.

То есть суть изначально в том, чтобы разделить тех, кому доступ давать и кому нет.

Если же Вам надо ограничить доступ для всех, или для всех, кроме используемого ip, то воспользуйтесь примером Ivan Bolnikh, добавив в исключения необходимый ip.